# Update of domain object fails

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, groovy

When I store a specific domain object (grom) in my grails-2.1.1 Application, I get the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
```

I use mysql as my database. I just want to persist my domain object. I tried to replace the logic inside my controller by

```
def hauptprojektInstance = Hauptprojekt.get(params.id)
hauptprojektInstance.save(flush: true)
```

but even this query fails with the same error.

The Hauptprojekt-domain model has a OneToMany and a OneToOne relation to other objects.

Comment: Can you post the 'HauptProjekt' domain class and its dependecies?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4110258

Comment: OK, that's big. My first idea: you're using inheritance. By default, the inheritance is using "table-per-hierarchy", so all the "nullable:false" constraint cannot be used, because thanks to the hierarchy, there are going to be null columns. Try to write a unit test, which fills in all hte possible attributes, both own and inherited, and try to call save(), if the problem persits.

Comment: Please pay attention that if you have added a nullable costrain after the first database generation grails don't alter the mysql table to mirror your new domain constrain. 
So try to verify if your mysql database schema nullable columns are corrected.